# groupby and aggregate for a certain range of months (Nov-June)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data set as below:

```
       time             Value
2006-09-15 00:00:00      1.27
2006-09-16 00:00:00        0
2006-09-17 00:00:00        0
2006-09-18 00:00:00     1.016
2006-09-19 00:00:00      5.08
2006-09-20 00:00:00      0.16
2006-09-21 00:00:00      3.81
```

I was wondering which method would be the best to do a groupby.sum for Nov to June instead of calendar year.

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you have tried?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem individually. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you finished before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your time column is `datetime64[ns]` you can simply just filter your dataframe by the month and sum. Based on your question you do not care about grouping by the year.

```
# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': {0: 1.27, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.016, 4: 5.08, 5: 0.16, 6: 3.81},
 'time': {0: '2006-09-15 00:00:00',
  1: '2006-11-16 00:00:00',
  2: '2006-11-17 00:00:00',
  3: '2006-12-18 00:00:00',
  4: '2006-01-19 00:00:00',
  5: '2006-02-20 00:00:00',
  6: '2006-09-21 00:00:00'}})

# make sure column is datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# filter by month using .isin()
df[df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.month).isin([11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6])]['Value'].sum()
```

Or if you want to group on year and month in that range you will need  to add a year and month column and group on them:

```
# create sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': {0: 1.27, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.06, 3: 1.016, 4: 5.08, 5: 0.16, 6: 3.81},
 'time': {0: '2006-09-15 00:00:00',
  1: '2006-11-16 00:00:00',
  2: '2006-11-17 00:00:00',
  3: '2006-12-18 00:00:00',
  4: '2006-01-19 00:00:00',
  5: '2006-02-20 00:00:00',
  6: '2007-02-21 00:00:00'}})

# make sure time is in fact datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# create month and year columns to group on
df['Month'] = df['time'].map(lambda x: x.month)
df['Year'] = df['time'].map(lambda x: x.year)

# filter dataframe for your month range
df2 = df[df['Month'].isin([11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6])]

# groupby and sum value
df2.groupby(['Year','Month'])['Value'].sum()
```

Comment: I have a very large data set, is creating sample dataFrame needed ?

Comment: @gooner2018 the sample data set is just for an example. The example you provided would return an empty dataframe because all the months are September and fall outside your range of Nov-June

Comment: I mean assigning 0,1,2,.. to every record is not possible since I have a large data set.

Comment: @gooner2018 you are not assigning the month and year with a loop it will not take long to create a new column and map the information with a lambda function.

Comment: I should also use the lambda function in the first part of the code? where you are creating sample dataframe?

Comment: @gooner2018 just run the code from `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` down on your dataframe and it will work